# Facing issue NoMethodError (undefined method `include' for "56":String):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am facing issue while writing this code

```
def sim_state
   sim_employees = SimEmployee.find(params[:id].include(:employees))
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render :layout => false,
               :locals => {
                   :sim_employees => sim_employee
               }
      }
     end
end
```

and in my  sim_states.js.erb

```
$('#simState').text('<%= sim_employee.employees.app_state%>');
```

So it gives me this error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `include' for "56":String):

when i use it with includes then it gives

> undefined method `includes'

Please guide me how to solve this.

Comment: I have also tried `sim_employees = SimEmployee.include(:employees).where(:id => params[:id]).first ` but it gives me this `TypeError (wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)):`

Answer (score 0):

```
SimEmployee.find(params[:id].include(:employees))
```

This line is causing the issue, you are calling `include(:employees)` on `params[:id]` which would be a number.

And you can't actually do `.find(params[:id].include(:employees)` because `find` method returns an instance of Model class, in this case, an instance of `SimEmployee` class, and you can't run method `include` on it.

**Edit:**

```
SimEmployee.includes(:employees).where()
```

You can pass a hash in `where()`. This works if your `SimEmployee` model has `has_many` relation to `Employee` model.

Comment: I have also tried sim_employees = SimEmployee.include(:employees).where(:id => params[:id]).first
TypeError (wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)):

Comment: It is not `include`, it is rather `includes` with an `s` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple

```
params[:id]
```

is return you a **String** value which is **"56"** and includes works with **ActiveRecord::Relation** and not string. So you are not able to fire the query that ways.

```
SimEmployee.find(params[:id])
```

This will return again a result and not relation. Try using

```
SimEmployee.where(id: params[:id]).includes(:employees).first
```

This should help you.

PS :  Using includes for one record is same as firing two independent queries i.e.

```
 @sim_employee = SimEmployee.find(params[:id])
 @emplyess = @sim_employee.employees
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this:

```
SimEmployee.includes(:employees).find params[:id]
```